# Table with index as parameter in function

Tags: lua, lua-table

Can I do this? Keep attention at the parameters and index:

```
function drawBox(box, id)
  love.graphics.setColor(box[id].color.r, box[id].color.g, box[id].color.b, 70)
  love.graphics.rectangle('fill', box[id].pos.x, box[id].pos.y, box[id].w, box.h)
  love.graphics.setColor(box[id].color.r/2, box[id].color.g/2, box[id].color.b/2)
  love.graphics.rectangle('line', box[id].pos.x, box[id].pos.y, box[id].w, box[id].h)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `box` table stores other tables. So you can do:

```
function drawBox(box)
  love.graphics.setColor(box.color.r, box.color.g, box.color.b, 70)
  love.graphics.rectangle('fill', box.pos.x, box.pos.y, box.w, box.h)
  love.graphics.setColor(box.color.r/2, box.color.g/2, box.color.b/2)
  love.graphics.rectangle('line', box.pos.x, box.pos.y, box.w, box.h)
end

drawBox(some_boxes[id])
```

Comment: That won't work as it seems that even if I pass in the table with desired index, "the setColor" function isn't recognizing "box.color.r" reference, because it should be with index: box[id].color.r. This approach isn't that good, any suggestions?

Comment: @sakvojaz, `setColor()` has nothing to do with the data you passed. If `box.color` is not there, that means it wasn't there as `all_boxes[id].color` too. After all, `box` in `drawBox()` arguments is the same object as `all_boxes[id]`. Check that you fixed all calls to `drawBox`, and there's no calls with old arguments agreements. You must pass single box, and not the table of all boxes plus id.